# how to delete partial contents in every lines under vim?

Tags: vim, vi

I am a newbie for vim's replacement commands.

I have a file diff.txt (from using command diff) which has the following contents:

```
 Files ./a/src/external/bdb/Table.cc and /home/b/src/external/bdb/Table.cc differ
 Files ./a/src/external/bdb/Table.h and /home/b/src/external/bdb/Table.h differ
 Files ./a/src/modules/catalog/distributed/CatalogBox.h and /home/b/src/modules/catalog/distributed/CatalogBox.h differ
```

in this file, every line includes some contents I don't want, I hope this file's final version as follows:

```
 Files ./a/src/external/bdb/Table.cc 
 Files ./a/src/external/bdb/Table.h 
 Files ./a/src/modules/catalog/distributed/CatalogBox.h
```

Of course I can use the following gawk and mv commands finish this task:

```
 gawk -F" " '{print $1 $2}' ./diff.txt > diff.txt.bak
 mv diff.txt.bak diff.txt
```

but I think vim must have a simple resolution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this command:

```
:%s/ and .*//
```

Comment: @key Thank you very much! I forgot using replacement command ^_^

Comment: Just a little `regex`

Answer (score 3):

except for `:s` command, you could try this too:

```
:%norm! 2WD
```

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with this at all.  Could you add an explanation?  I can't seem to find anything on `norm`.

Comment: Nevermind, I found it.  `norm` is short for [`normal`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/29.html) which works like physically typing the following commands.  The `!` forces it to use the original key bindings in case the user has rebound anything.  The `2WD` is standard Vim stuff.
Question: do we always get to assume that the `normal` command starts from the beginning of the line?